# zeroes of a continuous function

Tags: complex-analysis

This problem is an Exercise in the book "Twenty One Lectures on Complex Analysis" by A. Isaev :

Assume that $f:{\bf C}\rightarrow{\bf C}$ is a continuous function for which there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $$f^k + {a_{k-1}}f^{k-1}+\cdots + {a_{1}}f +{a_0} \equiv 0.$$ Prove that $f$ must be a constant function.

The author does not clarify what he means by the expression $``f^k"$.  Is it the $k$-fold composite of $f$ with itself? Or is it the function obtained by raising a given value $f(z_0)$ say to the $k$-th power? I would be grateful for any illumination. At any rate, I assumed that he meant $f(z_0)^k$, (this was inspired by the result for polynomials-in that case we would be working with $f(z) = z$). And I tried to argue (as for polynomials) by induction on $k$. The case $k=1$ seems to work as follows. If $f(z) + a_0 = 0$ for all $z\in{\bf C}$, then it must be the case that $f(z) = -a_0$ for all $z\in{\bf C}$. So the assertion follows. Assume it holds for $k-1$. Here I am stuck! With polynomials one would at this point appeal to the remainder theorem. But here I am unclear how to proceed! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it means the $k$th power, and that the hypothesis is that there is a non-constant polynomial $p$ such that $p(f(z))\equiv0$.

Comment: $f$ can take only finitely many values (polynomials have finitely many roots) and by continuity  it can take only one then

Comment: Your argument does not depend on induction (which is good!) I suppose as the coefficients $a_0,\cdots ,a_{k-1}$ are fixed, we are really only working with a polynomial after all.